# Merge MyDbContext with IdentityDbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a MyDbContext in a separated Data Accass Layer class library project. And I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project with a default IdentityDbContext. The two context use the same database, and I want to use AspNetUsers table to foreign key for some my tables.
So I would like to merge the two Context, and I want to use ASP.NET Identity too.

How can I do this?

Please advice,

This is my Context after merge:

```
public class CrmContext : IdentityDbContext<CrmContext.ApplicationUser> //DbContext
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public Int16 Area { get; set; }
        public bool Holiday { get; set; }
        public bool CanBePublic { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
    
    public CrmContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        
    }
    
    public DbSet<Case> Case { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CaseLog> CaseLog { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Parameter> Parameter { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Sign> Sign { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Template> Template { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Read> Read { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Here is my RepositoryBase class:

```
    public class RepositoryBase<TContext, TEntity> : IRepositoryBaseAsync<TEntity>, IDisposable
        where TContext : IdentityDbContext<CrmContext.ApplicationUser> //DbContext
        where TEntity : class
    {
        private readonly TContext _context;
        private readonly IObjectSet<TEntity> _objectSet;

        protected TContext Context
        {
            get { return _context; }
        }

        public RepositoryBase(TContext context)
        {
            if (context != null)
            {
                _context = context;
                //Here it is the error:
                _objectSet = (_context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
             }
             else
             {
                 throw new NullReferenceException("Context cannot be null");
             }
         }
     }
```

An exception of type `'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException'` occurred in `EntityFramework.dll` but was not handled in user code.

Comment: What does `merge` mean in this context?

Comment: I second this question. The new Identity RTM seems to make referencing to User complicated.

Comment: 'Merge' means I want just one Context in the DAL project not two independent contexts in two projects, but using the same database.

Comment: Hi Martonx, I am facing the same problem now. Wondering how did you create your dbContext (CrmContext)? Is it created by edmx?

Comment: Hi Xavier, I'm using Code First, I don't have edmx.

Comment: How do you store data in & access the dbset tables once this is done?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Move the `ApplicationUser` definition to your DAL.
2. Inherit your `MyDbContext` from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` or `IdentityDbContext`
3. OnModelCreating - Provide the foreign key info.
4. Pass `MyDbContext` while creating the `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`

Comment: I tried this, and it seemed to work, but when I tried to make EF CF Migration, the migration failed because of missing foreign keys.

Comment: I updated my initial post. So everything build fine, and in runtime, I get that error in my ReposytoryBasa class.

Comment: So where the steps suggested helpful in achieving the questioned goal?

Comment: I already known these steps, but I will sign your Answer as Answer, because it is good to see these steps. I hope this topik will help everybody to solve this issue.

Comment: if I inherit MyDbContext from IdentityDbContext, there is no SaveChanges method

Comment: Is this the answer for this question? Do we need to inherit from `IdentityDbContext`? In http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613255(v=vs.108).aspx I see that `IdentityDbContext` has two `SaveChanges` methods.

Comment: @VansFannel, yes. You need to inherit from framework defined context. I suggest to review http://www.asp.net/identity for many different usage articles.

Comment: @jd4u Is it acceptable to add Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework as a dependency to your data access layer? This seems a bit odd.

Comment: @Toolkit: the IdentityDbContext class inherits from DbContext who has the SaveChanges method.

Answer (score 6):

You may get the following message if you follow the above steps but can't work out how to provide the key information.  The error you may receive is:

IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Context.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Create the two following classes

```
public class IdentityUserLoginConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin>
{

    public IdentityUserLoginConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(iul => iul.UserId);
    }

}

public class IdentityUserRoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserRole>
{

    public IdentityUserRoleConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(iur => iur.RoleId);
    }

}
```

In the OnModelCreating method within your Applications DbContext add the two configurations outlined above to the model:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserLoginConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserRoleConfiguration());

    }
```

This should now get rid of the error methods when your model is being created.  It did for me.

Comment: Hi, what is this HasKey? I got Error: The name 'HasKey' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Check that you have the correct imports.  You obviously don't have the correct references.  Are you sure you are referencing EntityFramework and it's the correct namespace import at the top of your class?

Answer (score 5):

It's worth noting that if you merge the DBContexts you are tying an authentication approach (ASP's Identity in this case) to the data access implementation (EF). From a code design point of view that could be seen as mixing your concerns and a violation of [Single Responsibility Principle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn253028%28v%3Dvs.108%29).

That's probably fine in the majority of cases, but if you want to reuse your data layer in other non-web applications (e.g. for a desktop or server app) this will present an issue because IdentityDbContext lives in the [Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn253028%28v%3Dvs.108%29) namespace and your desktop or server apps are unlikely to be using AspNet Identity as their authentication mechanism.

We were in that situation and ended up keeping ASP's second DB Context, which stayed in the web project.  We then cross-loaded some of the data about the user (first name, last name, etc.) into the Identity's claims object when the user signed in.

Answer (score 4):

This may be an old thread, but this article was very helpful in demonstrating how to get the solution to the above question working:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/20/test-announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-0-0.aspx

I did end having to include

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
     //....
}
```

because without it, I would get the following error:

> EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
>   EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.

If I add these configurations as mentioned above:

```
public class IdentityUserLoginConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserLogin>
{
    public IdentityUserLoginConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(iul => iul.UserId);
    }
}

public class IdentityUserRoleConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserRole>
{
    public IdentityUserRoleConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(iur => iur.RoleId);
    }
}
```

it would create an additional foreign key called Application_User.

Answer (score 1):

1) After you inherit the context from IdentityDbContext errors related to primary keys on the Identity tables (AspNetUsers etc) should disappear.

2) Your ApplicationUser extension of IdentityUser is missing navigation properties that are interpreted as foreign keys by the Entity Framework (these are also very useful for navigation from your code).

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public Int16 Area { get; set; }
    public bool Holiday { get; set; }
    public bool CanBePublic { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    //*** Add the following for each table that relates to ApplicationUser (here 1-to-many)
    public virtual IList<Case> Cases { get; set; } //Navigation property
    //*** and inside the case class you should have 
    //*** both a public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser {get;set;}
    //*** and a public string ApplicationUserId {get;set;} (string because they use GUID not int)
}
```

3) I read in many places that when overiding OnModelCreating, you have to call the base method. It seems that sometimes you can do without it.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
         //....
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have given a complete answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35722688/1262198).
Here is the short answer:

Based on IdentityDbContext source code if we want to merge IdentityDbContext with our DbContext we have two options:
**First Option:**
Create a DbContext which inherits from IdentityDbContext and have access to the classes.

```
   public class ApplicationDbContext 
    : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    // Add additional items here as needed
}
```

**Second Option:**(Not recommended) 
We actually don't have to inherit from IdentityDbContext if we write all the code ourselves. 
So basically we can just inherit from DbContext and implement our customized version of "OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)" from the [IdentityDbContext source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityDbContext.cs)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused because You overwrote the content of method "OnModelCreating" which is implemented in IdentityUser class.

You need to call OnModelCreating method from the base class first, and after that add your code. So Your method OnModelCreating should look like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

     modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove this naming convention:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

And migrate the ef cf model to db, to rename my tables with the naming conventions of asp.net identity. It is working now!

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/19764233/3) to the question [Merge MyDbContext with IdentityDbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764233/merge-mydbcontext-with-identitydbcontext) by the OP [martonx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1522011/martonx) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>

Answer (score -2):

I tried a simple way.. copy the connection string from your db and replace the connection string of DefaultConnection. Go ahead and create user, all the necessary tables are automatically created in your database.

Hope that helps