# Merge MyDbContext to Asp.net IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I saw a lot of examples online but none that I could use from top to bottom about merging my own DbContext with Asp.net IdentityDbContext.

Can someone please walk me through it? I am at step 0, and what I want is to have the tables generated by ASP.net IdentityDbContext inside my own database, so that I can retain user data in my own database. How can I achieve that?

Thanx in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge MyDbContext with IdentityDbContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764233/merge-mydbcontext-with-identitydbcontext)

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correct, you are trying to use your existing database, tables and existing users with asp.net identity framework.

First thing, according to my understanding, you can't merge your db context (MyDbContext) with 'IdentityDbContext', because context of asp.net identity framework tables has to be inherited from `IdentityDbContext<YourUserTable>`. But your other tables may inherited from `DbContext`.

Therefore you have to use two separate db contexts if you want to use identity framework build in method support, which is UserManager etc.

You can use your existing database with identity framework, you just need to correctly bind your database tables with identity framework EF code first approach using model binding.

There is a YouTube video tutorial which may help you to get some idea in order to achieve your task. Actually this video illustrates to use Identity 2.0 with existing database.

Part 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elfqejow5hM

Part 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbSqi3Amatw

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve but check this question to see if it's of any help.

[ASP.NET Identity DbContext confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19902756/687549)

Answer (score 0):

Here's part of a walk-through I created. There are a few steps included specific to making it work with code first migrations but you should be able to accomplish what you want using these steps.

Start by creating a new ASP.NET MVC project. Call it Contacts if you want the included code to match. The authentication defaults to Individual User Accounts which is what we want in this case. Deselect Host in the Cloud for now. You can enter your publishing settings later. Once the project is created bring up the Package Manager Console and Install-Package EntityFramework. Now since we are doing Code First add a simple model class.

```
public class Contact {
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

At this point you would usually add controllers and such but since this post is focusing on the data side of things we'll skip over all of that. Next we want to add our database context. Go ahead and add it right in the Models namespace.

```
public class ContactContext : IdentityDbContext {
    public ContactContext()
        : base("ContactContext") {
    }

    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public static ContactContext Create() {
        return new ContactContext();
    }
}
```

A couple of things to note here. Since we're consolidating the Identity tables into our application's context we want to inherit from IdentityDbContext instead of just DbContext. Also, I prefer not to use the generated "DefaultConnection" that gets created in Web.config so I'm passing "ContactContext" as the connection string name to the base constructor. We'll modify the connection string in a minute. If you're typing in the OnModelCreating method Visual Studio should add the call to base.OnModelCreating but if not make sure you add it since it's essential for building the identity tables. Although not essential, you can configure the modelBuilder not to pluralize table names. Add a Create method which is needed for the Identity code to use this context. Also, as you add code you'll need to right-click and Resolve to add the appropriate using statements.

As promised, here is the modified connection string to be updated in the web.config in the root of the site. The name property is changed to something that makes sense for the application and the AttachDbFilename and Initial Catalog values are changed to something a little more user friendly than the auto generated name.

```
<add name="ContactContext" connectionString="Data Source=
(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ContactContext.mdf;Initial
Catalog=ContactContext;Integrated Security=True" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Now go to the Models folder and open the IdentityModels.cs file. Cut the ApplicationUser class from here and paste it into your Contact.cs file. Again you'll have to resolve a few missing namespaces. At this point you can safely delete the IdentityModels.cs file. Since we've eliminated the ApplicationDbContext we'll need to do a find on ApplicationDbContext and replace it with ContactContext in a few places. You should be able to do a clean build.