# How to make asp identity use my database instead of the automatically created mdf database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm working on a project which has two solutions, the first one is a desktop app where the admin does all the management from, he can add users, remove them etc.
On the web part the user can register, login etc. I can't make the asp identity use my own database, whenever i change the connection string i get the following error **[Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers'.]** which means there isn't such table.
I thought that asp.net identity will automatically create those tables. Do I need to do it manually ? Scripting the tables manually and making asp.net identity use them after would be a lot better. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved this with sql managment studio. I opened the mdf file I had in my AppData folder with sqlms, then I right clicked newly created database, hovered over tasks and clicked generate scripts. I marked all the tables, and created a script. Then I ran that script with my database and it works perfectly now. Here is the script:

```
USE [aspnet-HotelsWeb-20150427120248]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]    Script Date: 23.5.2015 19:47:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory](
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ContextKey] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MigrationId] ASC,
    [ContextKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetRoles]    Script Date: 23.5.2015 19:47:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles](
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]    Script Date: 23.5.2015 19:47:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ClaimType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ClaimValue] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]    Script Date: 23.5.2015 19:47:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins](
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LoginProvider] ASC,
    [ProviderKey] ASC,
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]    Script Date: 23.5.2015 19:47:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles](
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC,
    [RoleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUsers]    Script Date: 23.5.2015 19:47:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEndDateUtc] [datetime] NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserClaims] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserClaims_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserLogins] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserLogins_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetRoles] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetRoles_RoleId]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AspNetUserRoles_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have two `DbContext`s. If you want `Identity` to generate those table for you, you should probably just make your `DbContext` inherit from `IdentityDbContext` and you'll be all set. You can check this Stackoverflow question on how to [Merge MyDbContext with IdentityDbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19765928/2226079).

You'll also want to add a migration.

Something you should probably know is that `IdentityDbContext` isn't black magic, it's just a `DbContext` with a few predifined `DbSet`s you can checkout the source [here](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/2.0.0-rtm-140221/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework).