# How can I merge my SQL Server database with MVC auto implemented mdf database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to enable migrations for my database, then it gave me the following errors:

> More than one context type was found in the assembly 'The Factory Chante'.
>   To enable migrations for 'The_Factory_Chante.Models.ApplicationDbContext', use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName The_Factory_Chante.Models.ApplicationDbContext.
>   To enable migrations for 'The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext',  use Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName The_Factory_Chante.Models.The_FactoryDBContext.

I then quickly realised that I have two databases in my solution and I would like merge the `The_Factory_Chante.Models.ApplicaticayionDBContext` auto implemented database by MVC with my already existing database.

Answer (score 0):

go to tools package manager console in Visual  studio enter Enable-Migration then enter  Update Database -Verbose

if it fails

You will then need to specify which configuration you want to use when updating the databases.

```
Update-Database -ConfigurationTypeName MyRenamedConfiguration
```

Comment: Does this merge the databases? I do want to have only one database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764233/merge-mydbcontext-with-identitydbcontext  see this link @user3466153