# How to combine Identity context and EF Context in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am developing my first project in ASP.NET MVC and I want to improve, what I already done. I have web application with [identity authorization](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity),
so every user can login using his own credentials.

I have done `event/applicationuser model`, controller a views, so I can display, modify or delete events as well as users.

What I want to do is, that every user should have option to choose one or more events and sign up for selected event. As well as user should be able to see all his events after successful log in.

So I have to create new model for communicate between user and event. The problem is, that user inherits by `IdentityDbContext` and event by `DbContext`. Does anyone know some simple way to solve my problem?

This is my code:

1, ApplicationUser

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {

      public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
      {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
      }

    }
```

2, Event model

```
 public class Event
{

    public int ID { get; set; } 

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }

    public string EventLocation { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

3, Event context

```
public class Context:DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Event> Event { get; set; }
```

4, Model EventParticipant to communicate between user and event - not working

```
public class EventParticipant
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Event { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19764233/merge-mydbcontext-with-identitydbcontext

Comment: Just use the single ApplicationDbContext. Move your app DbSets and Models there.

Answer (score 0):

the Identity has ApplicationDbContext class for identity context.
i go to the ApplicationDbContext class and set it partial and create one class with same name and set it partial.
I write my configuration of context in my class
and create my migration without any Problems.